# Acess Attributes from WX Forms

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Given the following code [Gist](https://gist.github.com/zoiobnu/6755e30eb2ca2a3ef3d74d0d729155ba)

I'm trying to use attributes from my parent class , but i can't access then.

```
    src = BluTools.sourceFile.GetValue()
    dest = BluTools.destFile.GetValue()
    codigo_empresa = BluTools.codigo_empresa.GetValue()
    codigo_deposito = BluTools.codigo_deposito.GetValue()
    data = BluTools.data_inicio.GetValue()
```

But give-me error :

```
    AttributeError: 'BluTools' object has no attribute 'sourceFile'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on how classes work in Python. You do not normally access attributes by calling the class directly. You need to either create an instance of the class:

```
blue = BluTools()
blue.some_attr()
```

Or in your case, use `self` instead of `BluTools`

```
src = self.sourceFile.GetValue()
dest = self.destFile.GetValue()
codigo_empresa = self.codigo_empresa.GetValue()
codigo_deposito = self.codigo_deposito.GetValue()
data = self.data_inicio.GetValue()
```

Comment: Thanks , i fixed that problem but yeah , sometimes i freeze and forgot how works , kkk